# User input that refers to a string array that contains numbers in discord.py

Tags: python, input, discord, discord.py

I am currently learning discord.py and the making of discord bots. So i am working on a feature that spams a text or whatever. To do so i ask the user who he wants to spam, and how many times. And it's for this last one that i need help.

I tried to form an array in range, going from 1 to 30, and converting it to a string variable. It actually works, but the problem is when i try to collect user's input

code below

```
import *

num = []
for i in range(1,31):
    i+1
    num.append(i)
NUMBERS_SPAM = [str(x) for x in num]
del num
print(NUMBERS_SPAM)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    def check(m):
        for number in NUMBERS_SPAM:
            return m.content == number and m.channel.send == message.channel.send

    msg1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await message.channel.send("let's spam")
```

I thought it would work, but actually the bot only answers when i enter 1, although i want it to answer when he reads an int from 1 to 30

Thanks a lot to anyone who would be helping me out !!

Comment: You can dm me on discord `Blackcoffee#9911` I will try to help ya out

Comment: `i+1` inside loop is totally useless. Besides it is much simpler `num = list(range(1, 31))` Or even `NUMBERS_SPAM = [str(x) for x in range(1, 31)]` without `num`.

Comment: `return` exists function on first loop - which use value `1`. You should rather check `if m.content in NUMBERS_SPAM` without `for`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` exits on first loop when `number` is `1` - so it check only one value.

You should use `if ... in ...` instead of  `for ... in ...` and `==`

```
def check(m):
    return (m.content in NUMBERS_SPAM) and (m.channel.send == message.channel.send)
```

Comment: Bro thanks a lot it's actually so simple gg !!!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to prompt a user to spam x (user) y amount of times, keep it simple.

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, user : discord.User, amount = 1):
    await ctx.reply("Spamming {} {} times.".format(user,amount))
    for i in range(amount): await user.send(i)
```